# Wix - Use WixVariables on .wixproj

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, project, msbuild-task, ms-project

i'm on Visual Studio 2012 and i use [wix](http://wixtoolset.org/)

I wanted to use a WixVariables or a DefineConstants on Target After build (wixproj) when i unload the project

i used on

```
<DefineConstants>VersionNodeServer=0.0.1;</DefineConstants>
```

Or

```
<WixVariables>VersionNodeServer=0.0.1;</WixVariables>
```

but when i used this variable 'VersionNodeServer' like that

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
<WebDownload FileName="test.msm" FileUri="$(VersionNodeServer)"/>
```

the build failed because FileUri is empty.

i saw my variable on the VS console ..

> C:\Program Files\WiX Toolset v3.10\bin\candle.exe -dDebug
>   -dVersionNodeServer=0.0.1;[...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `<DefineConstants>` nor `<WixVariable>` define a variable for MSBUILD. You have to put

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <VersionNodeServer>0.1.1</VersionNodeServer>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

somewhere in your .wixproj file.

Comment: ooo :(, ok i wanted tu use a dynamic variable into msbuild, with candle... thx for this anwser !

Comment: Dynamic variables / properties together with MSBUILD is not that simple. Properties are created as one of the first steps inside MSBUILD but you might create a task that creates the properties which is a precondition for AfterBuild